# Making sure two values match in an array, while both are unknown to the software

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am coding a vocab-questioner for school and have gotten pretty far. At the moment I am stuck with an annoying bug where I have two arrays, one for the multiple answer choice and one for the correct answers.

When matching to see the correct answers I check with the same index in both arrays. So for example: `if(correctAnswers[0] === userAnswer[0]);` But the problem is that when the user enters the answers in another order, the answers become incorrect, which is wrong, they should be correct.

So obviously I am iterating through the arrays and checking how many of the answered answers are correct, but this doesn't work, because for example:

```
correctAnswers[0] === userAnswer[0] | CORRECT
correctAnswers[1] === userAnswer[1] | CORRECT
```

`correctAnswers[0] !== userAnswer[1] | INCORRECT` <- This is the problem when iterating through the arrays. The user has just put the answers in another order which shouldn't make the users answer wrong.

I expect the user to be able to answer in another order of the multiple answers that are present for the word.

Comment: Don't push the users' answers to the array, add them by the index to the array.

Comment: If the user can populate the answer array in any order, than either the structure needs to change to be an object that associates the question with the corresponding answer, *or* you need to figure out which question they're answering and put the answer in the correct index.

Comment: `Associative Arrays` is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Use one list of objects where each object holds the question and answer.

Comment: @Milk Yup, so if I understand it correctly I am supposed to make an array that looks for values that match (are the same) and remove them from the array? And if the array has values left not both answers from the user are not correct right?

Comment: reading the edited question, I can see the problem. I don't think using array is the best approach in this case. if you insist to compare those arrays (or you must use arrays because your teacher asked for), you will need to use a double `for` loop and compare the question with the answers, and save in other 2 variables the sum of corrects and the sum of wrongs choices.